# What to do when I am still waiting on an offer?

Tags: job-search, internship

I am currently employed at a company as an Intern. I have been interning for a while and my work has been praised by my colleagues and manager. I brought up a request for an offer to my manager because I will be completing my masters degree soon, but nothing has happened. It has been several months and I am not sure if I will get an offer despite my work. I have brought it up during several meetings with my manager and was told they need more time. From what I understand they are actively looking for employees, interviewing candidates, and even hired several employees recently which I have trained. What do I do to get an offer? Should I keep waiting or leave and try to get an offer elsewhere?

Edit: I am actively searching for other jobs but am trying to get an offer from my current employer. By leaving I will have more time to continue my job search since I am also a student.

Comment: "Should I keep waiting or leave and try to get an offer elsewhere?" Neither. You should look for a job elsewhere, but you should not leave until you have a contract in hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why do you need to leave to try and get an offer elsewhere?**

The reasons for them not providing you with an offer are not particularly relevant, although none make it a good place to work from a career perspective.

1. They don't want you permanently, but need you for now and are stringing you along
2. Your manager has only limited power in the organization
3. Your manager is forgetful, incompetent, or just doesn't prioritize this part of the job

The fix for all of them is another offer and given how they are behaving, I would lean towards leaving even if they later provided an offer. However, why do you need to leave to get that?

> By leaving I will have more time to continue my job search since I am also a student.

The trade-off here is that you have less leverage and appear less valuable. Employers far prefer those who are already working for the purposes of hiring. You will need to decide that trade off for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Matthew, I will continue to search for a career elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> *What to do when I am still waiting on an offer?*

keep on attending interviewing, until you get an offer - be it from another company or the current employer.

- If you get and accept the offer from the current employer, you can continue as usual and do not need to mention anything about other interviews.
- If you get a (better) offer outside the current organization, make sure you have it signed and sealed, then hand over the resignation,  serve the notice period (if applicable) and move on.